# How to make the following Halide code more efficient?

Tags: c++, halide

The code snippet below is running slower than expected. The authors of this paper http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Geiger2010ACCV.pdf compute support_points of a 900x700 image in 118 ms. I have implemented their algorithm below in Halide.
In my algorithm, the nested for loops over length and width iterate over xi and yi, which are points in output_x and output_y (defined previously but not shown below). Over each iteration of the nested for loops, a vector top_k is computed and pushed_back into support_points.
Computing this pipeline even for left_buffer.width() == 20 and left_buffer.height() == 20 takes 500 ms. Thus this implementation is several orders of magnitude slower:

```
...
    int k = 4; // # of support points
    vector<pair<Expr, Expr>> support_points(k * left_buffer.width() * left_buffer.height());
    // Calculate support pixel for each
    Func support("support");
    support(x, y) = Tuple(i32(0), i32(0), f32(0));


    for (int yi = 0; yi < left_buffer.height(); yi++) {
        for (int xi = 0; xi < left_buffer.width() - 2; xi++) {
            bool left = xi < left_buffer.width() / 4;
            bool center = (xi >= left_buffer.width() / 4 && xi < left_buffer.width() * 3 / 4);
            bool right = xi >= left_buffer.width() * 3 / 4;

            vector <pair<Expr, Expr>> scan_range;
            pair <Expr, Expr> scan_height(0, (Expr) left_buffer.height());
            pair <Expr, Expr> scan_width;
            int which_pred = 0;
            if (left) {

                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) 0, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 0;
            }
            else if (center) {
                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) xi - left_buffer.width() / 4, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 1;
            }
            else if (right) {
                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 2;
            }
            else {
                cout<<"Error"<<endl;
            }

            scan_range = {scan_width, scan_height};
//            cout<<"xi "<<xi<<endl;
//            cout<<"yi "<<yi<<endl;
//            cout<<"scan_width= "<<scan_width.first<<" "<<scan_width.second<<endl;
//            cout<<"scan_height= "<<scan_height.first<<" "<<scan_height.second<<endl;


            RDom scanner(scan_range);
            Expr predicate[3] = {scanner.x != xi && scanner.y != yi, scanner.x != 0 && scanner.y != 0, scanner.x != xi && scanner.y != yi};
            scanner.where(predicate[which_pred]);
            std::vector<Expr> top_k(k * 3);
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) { // say we want top 4 support points.
                top_k[3*i] = 10000.0f;
                top_k[3*i+1] = 0;
                top_k[3*i+2] = 0;
            }

            Func argmin("argmin");
            argmin() = Tuple(top_k);
            Expr next_val = abs(output_x(xi, yi) - output_x(scanner.x, scanner.y)) + abs(output_y(xi, yi) - output_y(scanner.x, scanner.y));
            Expr next_x = scanner.x;
            Expr next_y = scanner.y;

            top_k = Tuple(argmin()).as_vector();
            // Insert a single element into a sorted list without actually branching
            top_k.push_back(next_val);
            top_k.push_back(next_x);
            top_k.push_back(next_y);
            for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
                Expr prev_val = top_k[(i-1)*3];
                Expr prev_x = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1];
                Expr prev_y = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2];
                Expr should_swap = top_k[i*3] < prev_val;

                top_k[(i-1)*3] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3], prev_val);
                top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 1], prev_x);
                top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 2], prev_y);
                top_k[i*3] = select(should_swap, prev_val, top_k[i*3]);
                top_k[i*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, prev_x, top_k[i*3 + 1]);
                top_k[i*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, prev_y, top_k[i*3 + 2]);
            }
            // Discard the k+1th element
            top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back();

            bool cond = xi == 10 && yi == 10;
            cout << xi << " "<< yi << " " << cond << endl;

            Expr e = argmin()[0];

            e = print_when(cond, e, "<- argmin() val");
            argmin() = Tuple(top_k);
            argmin.compute_root();
//            argmin.trace_stores();


            argmin.compile_to_lowered_stmt("argmin.html", {}, HTML);
            Realization real = argmin.realize();
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                pair<Expr, Expr> c(top_k[3*i+1], top_k[3*i+2]);
                support_points.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }
    double t2 = current_time();

    cout<<(t2-t1)/100<<" ms"<<endl;
    cout<<"executed"<<endl;
}
```

How can I improve efficiency?

Comment: How exactly are you compiling the code (what compiler and what compiler options)? Are optimizations enabled?

Comment: For code reviews there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Just make sure to post working and complete code there.

Comment: you are creating a couple of vectors in every single iteration, cant you reuse them somehow?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, they can be pulled out and I tried it. Down to 423 ms. Thanks. Still, this should be running at the tune of < 100 ms

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be getting a bit confused between the stages of your program. With Halide, your C++ code that works with `Exprs`, `Funcs`, etc. is not actually evaluating anything, it is constructing a Halide program, which you can then compile and run. That means that the C++ `for` loops, `std::vectors`, etc. that you're using are all happening at program construction time (essentially compile time) of the Halide program. You might think of it like C++ templates, which evaluate at compile time, vs. the C++ code they construct, which evaluate at the run time of your program: the C++ code you're writing here is equivalent to template code with respect to the Halide program that you are building.

This gets a bit more confusing with the ability to JIT-compile and evaluate a Halide program inside of the same C++ program that builds it (`realize`).

As it is, I suspect the above program doesn't actually compute the results you expect it to. After the double `for` loop, what are you hoping to do with `support_points`? What you have built there is a big array of expressions (pieces of code), not concrete values. And you are JIT-compiling and running a new piece of Halide code each time around those loops (i.e., for every pixel).

I think you may have an easier time understanding what you are building if you stick to ahead-of-time compilation (`compile_to_file` or generators) for now. That makes the two stages—Halide code generation time, and the runtime of that code inside a separate program—very distinct.